# How to run this Python Project from Github?

Tags: python, github, project

so I've downloaded this project from github and to run this project it says to extract the folder which I've done, but I dont know what else to do to run this project. Following instructions after extracting the folder are..

Move to project folder in Terminal. Then run following Commands: python -m pip install -r requirements. txt

py manage.py makemigrations

py manage.py migrate

py manage.py runserver

Lastly it says to enter this URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Found the project on github.com/sumitkumar1503/bloodbankmanagement

Can anyone help me run this project please?

Comment: So, what's wrong with the instructions?

Comment: Hi, nothing wrong with instructions. I was just confused but managed to run it after all.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running it.
the requirements has missed one package so after pip install -r requirements. txt  run
pip install Pillow

then

py manage.py makemigrations

py manage.py migrate

py manage.py runserver

Please update the error message you are getting if this doesn't work.

**If you make a virtual environment for each project it will be more stable.**

**I suggest creating a venv for this project first so that there are no conflicts**

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I managed to download Pillow and later it worked